# WPF path shape title

Tags: wpf, path

I have a path shape, i want to set a label above the path ,i put a textblock above the path then i handle the Path_MouseEnter , Path_MouseLeave and change the path background the problem is when the mouse leave the path shape to textblock the background changed the other problem when i handle the Path_MouseDown , the textblock also make a problem is there a beter way to set a label above the path shape ?

```
    private void Path_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Path).Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
    }

    private void Path_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Path).Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightGray;
    }

    private void Path_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to follow, but I think you mean that you have a `TextBlock` overlayed on top of a `Path`, and when the mouse hits the textblock, your `Path_MouseLeave()` is triggered but your don't want it to be?

If this is the case, just set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the `TextBlock` to make it transparent to mouse events.